# How to modify AJAX request so that the empty dependent drop-down is hidden when page loads?

Tags: html, django, ajax

I have a form that has a dependent drop-down. Currently, it displays the main drop-down and the dependent one when the page loads, and when you select a "Work Area" that does not have a "Station", then the station drop-down disappears from the page.

What I'm trying to achieve is hiding the Station drop-down when the page first loads, and only have it show when a Work Area that does have Stations is selected. How could I modify the AJAX request (or the html tags, not sure where the change would have to occur) so that it is hidden from the beginning?

**enter_exit_area.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" data-stations-url="{% url 'operations:ajax_load_stations' %}" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div>
            <div>
                <label>Employee</label>
                {{ form.employee_number }}
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Work Area</label>
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Station</label>
                {{ form.station_number }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>
                <button type="submit" name="leave_area" value="Leave">Leave Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#id_work_area").change(function () {
            var url = $("#warehouseForm").attr("data-stations-url");
            var workAreaId = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    'work_area': workAreaId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#id_station_number").html(data);
                    // Check the length of the options child elements of the select
                    if ($("#id_station_number option").length == 1) {
                        $("#id_station_number").parent().hide(); // Hide parent of the select node
                    } else {
                        // If any option, ensure the select is shown
                        $("#id_station_number").parent().show();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
     </script>
{% endblock main %}
```

**station_number_dropdown_options.html**

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for station in stations %}
<option value="{{ station.pk }}">{{ station.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Not sure if this part is necessary, but just in case:

**views.py**

```
def load_stations(request):
    work_area_id = request.GET.get('work_area')
    stations = Station.objects.filter(work_area_id=work_area_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'operations/station_number_dropdown_options.html', {'stations': stations})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide your div initially.

```
        <div id="my-hidden-div" style="display:none">
            <label>Station</label>
            {{ form.station_number }}
        </div>
```

then in your ajax method :

```
 success: function (data) {
                    $("#my-hidden-div").show(); // show it
                    $("#id_station_number").html(data);

                    // Check the length of the options child elements of the select
                    if ($("#id_station_number option").length == 1) {
                        $("#id_station_number").parent().hide(); // Hide parent of the select node
                    } else {
                        // If any option, ensure the select is shown
                        $("#id_station_number").parent().show();
                    }
                }
```

or make an css rule

`#id_station_number {display:none}`

then show it in the success like this

```
$("#id_station_number").show();
```